# How to create instance of generic type with parameter

Tags: java, generics, types, instance

I have following class.

```
public class SomeClass<T extends CustomView> { 
    public void someMethod() {
        T t; // = new T(context) ...compile error!
        // I want instance of SomeType that have parameter(context) of constructor.
        t.go();
    }
}
```

I want to create an instance of generic type T with the parameter of the constructor.

I tried to `TypeToken`, `Class<T>`, `newInstance` and etc., but nothing to success. I want some help. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can't create a new instance of a generic.  Potentially instead you could create a factory that does that for you (so long as it's a type of `CustomView`, your class wouldn't care).

Answer (score 7):

You have two main choices.

## Reflection

This way is not statically type safe.  That is, the compiler gives you no protection against using types that don't have the necessary constructor.

```
public class SomeClass< T > {
    private final Class< T > clsT;
    public SomeClass( Class< T > clsT ) {
        this.clsT = clsT;
    }

    public someMethod() {
         T t;
         try {
             t = clsT.getConstructor( context.getClass() ).newInstance( context );
         } catch ( ReflectiveOperationException roe ) {
             // stuff that would be better handled at compile time
         }
         // use t
    }
}
```

## Factory

You have to declare or import a `Factory< T >` interface.  There is also an extra burden on the caller to supply an instance thereof to the constructor of `SomeClass` which further erodes the utility of your class.  However, it's statically type safe.

```
public class SomeClass< T > {
    private final Factory< T > fctT;
    public SomeClass( Factory< T > fctT ) {
        this.fctT = fctT;
    }
    public someMethod() {
         T t = fctT.make( context );
         // use t
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is working well, but I want use only type `<T>` in `SomeClass<T>`. isn't there way to unuse parameter `Class<T>` of constuctor? that is, how to make `Class<T>` instance of type <T>.

Comment: If you can pass in an actual instance of T, you can use either approach I mention.  The first works if you replace `clsT` with `t.getClass()`; the second works if you make sure `CustomView` is self-bounded and has a `make()` method